# scrapy response.txt has no HTML body

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm creating a very simple version of a web crawler, which extrapolates and counts some simple < li > tags from the bottom navbar on the page www.instagram.com

The following code works on any other website except on instagram:

```
import scrapy

class InstaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "insta_spider"
    start_urls = ["https://www.instagram.com/"]
    count = 1


def parse(self, response):
    SET_SELECTOR = ".K5OFK"
    for tag in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):
        self.count += 1
    print("My count is " + str(self.count))
```

The crawler yields the following code:

```
INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.instagram.com/> (referer: None)
My count is 1
```

so the page gets crawled but for some reason it won't find that particular class (or any other class on the instagram page) so it will yield a count of 1, instead of a count of 10 (There are 10 lis )

Interestingly, when I add

```
print(response.text)
```

I will only see what is in the head of the page source, whilst I won't see the body! No HTML in the body, as if instagram was shielding it. Any idea?